# LINQ ForEach Statement

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a struct:

```
struct Student
{
    string Name;
    int ClassesMissedToday;
}
```

I now have a list for the struct:

```
List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
```

How can I say the following in LINQ:

```
Students.Add(new Student { Name = "Bob", ClassesMissedToday = 2 }) 
Students.Add(new Student { Name = "Bob", ClassesMissedToday = 0 }) 
Students.Add(new Student { Name = "Joe", ClassesMissedToday = 0 })
Students.Add(new Student { Name = "Bob", ClassesMissedToday = 1 })
```

(pseudo code)

```
foreach Student.Name in Students:
   Console.WriteLine("Total Classes Missed Total: {0}", ClassedMissedToday(count all of them)
```

I know this is rather trivial to some, but for some reason I can't seem to find any valid example simplified.

Ideas?

Answer (score 9):

`Sum()` for the help:

```
int total = students.Sum(s => s.ClassesMissedToday);
```

---

Also you might find more useful collection initialization syntax since C# 3.0

```
var students = new List<Student>
{
    new Student { Name = "Bob", ClassesMissedToday = 2 },
    new Student { Name = "Bob", ClassesMissedToday = 0 },
    new Student { Name = "Joe", ClassesMissedToday = 0 },
    new Student { Name = "Bob", ClassesMissedToday = 1 }
};
```

This will do the same since would call `Add()` method for the each underlying entry of the collection being initialized.

Comment: +1. You may also consider more generic Aggregate method when Sum is not enough.

Comment: @Alaxei: not sure I'm following your idea, I know `Aggreagte()` but not sure how it might be more useful in such case?

Comment: "Sum" is the same as `students.Aggregate(0, (t,s ) => t + s.ClassesMissedToday);`, but allows more flexibility if one needs it (Sum is better for this particular case).

Answer (score 4):

To get the total count of classes missed for all students, you can use the `Sum` operator.

```
var totalMissed = students.Sum(s => s.ClassesMissedToday);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Total classes missed for all students is {0}", totalMissed);
```

To get the count of classes missed when grouped by student name, you can use the `GroupBy` and `Sum` operations along with an anonymous type.

```
var totals = students.GroupBy(s => s.Name).Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, TotalMissed = g.Sum(s => s.ClassesMissedToday) });
foreach (var u in totals)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Total classes missed today for {0} is {1}", u.Name, u.TotalMissed));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question assumes that this is an appropriate place to use a `ForEach` operator. You have a foreach loop in your question

```
foreach Student.Name in Students:
   Console.WriteLine("Total Classes Missed Total: {0}", 
       ClassedMissedToday(count all of them)
```

but do you really want to write a line to Console for each of the students?  It seems you simply want

```
Console.WriteLine("Total Classes Missed Total: {0}", 
    ClassedMissedToday(count all of them)
```

and you're asking 'How can I sum the classes missed?'.

You can do this with a number of LINQ operators - including the `ForEach` operator (as in Will Marcouiller's answer) - but you want to do it using the right tool. The right tool here is the `Sum` operator.

```
Console.WriteLine("Total Classes Missed Total: {0}", 
    ClassedMissedToday(Students.Sum(s => s.ClassesMissedToday))
```

Comment: +1 Nice one using Sum! I must say that I rarely have to sum things up that way, and I wonder whether I would have thought of it. Thanks anyway! =)

Answer (score 1):

```
int missed;
Students.ForEach(s => missed += s.ClassedMissedToday);
Console.WriteLine("Total : {0}", missed);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems odd. Are you sure you want to just sum the total missed days of all students? Looking at your pseudo-code it seems you mean to write out that student's missed days. If so...

If you group on the student name, you'd only go through each name once.

This is from my head so it might contain a typo. It's also not pretty...

```
Students.GroupBy(student => student.Name)
.Select(filtered => new object { Name = filtered.Name, Missed = filtered.Sum(groups => groups.ClassesMissedToday) })
.ToList()
.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} has missed {1} classes", s.Name, s.Missed)));
```

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?